# opengl в линуксе через Qt creator

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opengl, qtcreator

Сейчас работаю в Ubuntu (механический бобер). И решил собрать первую программу с использованием opengl (просто тупо окно)

---

через консоль "до качал" библиотеки

```
sudo apt-get install qtcreator libglfw3-dev libglm-dev libepoxy-dev libboost-all-dev libglew-dev
```

---

Вот .про файл

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
#CONFIG -= app_bundle
#CONFIG -= qt

QT += opengl

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

В вот сама программа , все заголовчные файлы подключились без проблем.

```
#include <iostream>
// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// Include GLEW. Always include it before gl.h and glfw3.h, since it's a bit magic.
#include <GL/glew.h>
// Include GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
// Include GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Initialise GLFW
     glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
        return -1;
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4); // 4x antialiasing
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // We want OpenGL 3.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); // We don't want the old OpenGL

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    GLFWwindow* window; // (In the accompanying source code, this variable is global for simplicity)
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);
    if( window == NULL ){
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental=true; // Needed in core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    do{
        // Clear the screen. It's not mentioned before Tutorial 02, but it can cause flickering, so it's there nonetheless.
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        // Draw nothing, see you in tutorial 2 !

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
           glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );

    return 0;
}
```

Но почему то не видит ссылки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже qmake не подставляет какую-то библиотеку в линковщик. Попробуйте указать вручную. В проекте:

```
LIBS += -lGLEW -lglfw -lOpenGL
```

Библиотеки также добавляются из меню правой кнопкой мыши на .pro файле -> Добавить библиотеку. В появившемся мастере выбираем нужные пункты.
После этого библиотека должна автоматически прописаться.

Comment: увы, не так всё очевидно, я обновлял через команду `apt-get` и совершенно не смог найти файлов с расширением .so (этих библиотек). Хотя заголовочные файлы присутствуют.

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/libglfw3/filelist

Answer (score 1):

Линковщик говорит, что не может разрешить ссылки на функции. Вам необходимо подключить соответствующую библиотеку.

Чтобы подключить библиотеку в Qt Creator, нужно нажать правой кнопкой мыши на проекте, затем "Добавить библиотеку". Выбрать тип компонуемой библиотеки "Внешняя". Потом выбрать тип библиотеки "Linux (lib*.so lib*.a)". Выбрать файл библиотеки и путь к заголовочному файлу, платформу. В .pro файл добавится все необходимое.

Answer (score 0):

в общем нашёл где лежат файлы, через файловый менеджер ***Krusader***, а файловый менеджер ***PCManFM*** меня подвёл и через поиск не показывал файлы с расширением `.so`

Добавил "внешние" библиотеки. Они лежат в директории `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` а заголовочные в директории `/usr/include`

Теперь **.pro** файл выглядит так :

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
#CONFIG -= app_bundle
#CONFIG -= qt

QT += opengl

SOURCES += main.cpp

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lOpenGL

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/include/GL

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lGLEW

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/include/GL

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lglfw

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/include/GLFW
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/include/GLFW
```

И всё заработало :3 *(main.cpp остался прежним)*